# Pulling multiple tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I have multiple tables that I'm trying to basically form one SQL string on. Example of tables:

Table1

```
CardID    CardName    SetID    Rarity
1         Card #1     1        1
2         Card #2     1        2
3         Card #3     1        2
4         Card #4     2        2
```

Table 2

```
SetID     SetName     BID
1         Set #1      1
2         Set #2      2
```

Table 3

```
BID       BName
1         BName #1
2         BName #2
```

What I would like is an SQL string that would count the cards for a set and show the rarity for each card in that table. I want an output something similar to:
SetID, SetName, BName, TotalCards, Total of Rarity 1, Total of Rarity 2

So output would be similar to returning columns:

```
1, Set #1, BName #1, 3, 1, 2
2, Set #2, BName #2, 1, 0, 1
```

Comment: It helps to label the columns of the output you want, along with the tables the columns come from.  Do you want the output in a single column as a comma delimited list?

Comment: No, not as a comma delimited list. The last 3  columsn in the return would use the Count() somehow. It would be something like: SetID, SetName, BName, Count(Total cards for that set ID), Count(Total cards for that SetID that = Rarity of 1), Count(Total cards for the SetID that = Rarity of 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c.SetID
  , s.SetName
  , b.BName 
  , count(*) as TotalCards
  , sum(if(c.rarity = 1,1,0) as Total_of_Rarity_1
  , sum(if(c.rarity = 2,1,0) as Total_of_Rarity_2
FROM card c
INNER JOIN `set` s ON (s.SetID = c.SetID)
INNER JOIN b on (b.BID = s.BID)
GROUP BY c.SetID
```

Links: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: So many SQL questions translate to not just knowing how to do joins or aggregate queries.